# JSON object crash with html enteties

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have following PHP script which create a JSON object from the MySQL tables.

```
$arr = array();

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT post_title, post_content, meta_value FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN    wp_postmeta ON ID = post_id and meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' ");

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
$arr[] = $obj;
}
echo '{"members":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

One of the columns in my table is called `post_content`, which contains html entities such as url links. It is this that makes the program crash.

How can I resolve this issue?

Crash [image]

Comment: Is the data from the Db UTF-8 encoded? That might cause issues

Comment: crash?? show the json output

Comment: FYI: You should be doing `echo json_encode(array('members' => $arr));` instead.  Don't try to build a JSON string by hand, let PHP do it for you.

Comment: What does "makes the program crash" mean?  What errors/messages/output do you see?  What does `var_dump($arr);` show?  What JSON is being echoed?

Comment: I've added a picture. Here you can see that i've added and it seem to cant create the json object correctly

Comment: Try to view the source of that page.  Your browser is trying to render the HTML tags in there and is failing.  Chances are, the JSON is fine and the error is just how you are viewing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://php.net/json_encode, you must add  a second parameter to make it escape correctly..

```
JSON_HEX_TAG
All < and > are converted to \u003C and \u003E. Available since PHP 5.3.0.
```

Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php